# Magento Reindexing + Catalog page issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento, magento-1.7

I'm quite a new developer for magento and I have these issues that i'm unable to solve which I think is linked together.
Firstly, when trying to reindex the catalog url rewrite I get an error saying "An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite"
I have tried many suggestions on the web to solve this (including truncating the whole core_url_rewrite) but I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

Also in some of the category pages, I am getting a "There has been an error processing your request" page that is embedded into where products should be listed. However this is only a problem for some category pages (mostly level 2 except one of them is still working fine and a single level 3 category page) The error log is as follows:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1407:"SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`bss_weight`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='434'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 ORDER BY `price_index`.`min_price` asc LIMIT 20

";i:1;s:5326:"#0 /home/pharmapost/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/pharmapost/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/pharmapost/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/pharmapost/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT 1 AS `st...', Array)
#4 /home/pharmapost/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT 1 AS `st...', Array)
#5 /home/pharmapost/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT 1 AS `st...', Array)
#6 /home/pharmapost/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT 1 AS `st...', Array)
#7 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1047): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT 1 AS `st...')
#8 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Observer.php(78): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Review_Model_Observer->catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1311): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Review_Model_Observer), 'catalogBlockPro...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#13 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(163): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#14 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#15 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#17 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(85): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#18 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/design/frontend/pharmapost/default/template/easyspotlight/category/view.phtml(46): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#19 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/pharmapos...')
#20 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/pharma...')
#21 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#25 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#27 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/design/frontend/pharmapost/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#28 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/pharmapos...')
#29 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/pharma...')
#30 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#31 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#32 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#34 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#35 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#36 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#37 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#38 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#39 /home/pharmapost/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#40 /home/pharmapost/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#41 {main}";s:3:"url";s:47:"/catalog/category/view/s/natural-health/id/434/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Any guidance/help on the problem or where to look would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1
Although reindexing flat table didn't help, disabling the flat products did fix it but is there any way of solving the problem so that I can have the flat products enabled? Also I still can't reindex the catalog url rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you have some problems with flat. Firstly try these steps:

1. Backup your database
2. Truncate catalog_product_flat_* tables
3. Reindex catalog_product_flat

**upd.1**

- Try to disable flat and reproduce the described issue.
- Try to determine which product cause and issue. Find the category with the
  minimal number of products. Create test category and assign these
  products one by one on it. Try to define which product cause an issue.
- What is the result of execution of the query from the top of your post?

Comment: I've tried it but this seems to have no effect at all :(

Comment: Please check two tips from the post below.

Comment: Ok, check point number 2. Now we know that problem is caused by flat

Comment: When I've disabled flat, problematic category pages work fine but I'm unable to pin point the product. Also when I enable flat, create a test category and move a subcategory into this, it causes 404 due to url rewrite problems and since I can't reindex catalog url rewrite, which just returns error.

Comment: I've used the query and it seemed the problem was with the recent running out of diskspace forcing overflow /tmp , causing space shortage. I've freed up diskspace and rebooted everything and everything is working fine. Thank you!